# How to allow all programs and libraries of a package at once?

Tags: security, package-management, authorization

I would like to install the SageMath package (Binaries available at http://www-ftp.lip6.fr/pub/math/sagemath/osx/intel/index.html) on macOS.

The problem is that when I unpack the package and I try to access it, then the "Python3.8" program is blocked. I know that problem and I correct it by adding the permission in "Security & Privacy". The problem is that after I allow **Python3.8** then other libraries are blocking. Authorizing them one by one does not appear to work as at some point the same library show up.

Is there a way to allow the package all at once? I am fine with having the untrusted programs being blocked, but I would appreciate if a single operation would be needed to unblock them.

From the above mentioned web site, I tried the **.tar.bz2** and the **.dmg** and the same problem occurs. If there is one way to address this in a software way when the **.dmg** is created I would be interested as I am in contact with the Sage community.

Comment: Have you tried installing with Homebrew: [https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/sage](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/sage)

Comment: Thanks! That indeed a solution. I found on the sage forum that a solution to my problem is "sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine <path/to/Sage>"